# I am failing ailing to scrape an ASP site after page 10

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

The website I am scrapping is:

**http://isystems.hpcsa.co.za/iregister/RegisterSearch.aspx**

I am getting to page 10 with my code that is looking at the pagination numbers and iterating over them but it is failing when it wants to get past page 10 because there are three dots (...) that, if you click in the browser, it loads page 11 (Same for after page 20, page 30 etc). How can I update my code below so that it can deal with this error without breaking?

The code I am using is:

```
import re
import string
import urlparse

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class DoctorScraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "http://isystems.hpcsa.co.za/iregister/RegisterSearch.aspx"
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

    def scrape(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)

        # choose to search using the region 
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_id('SearchChkb_5').click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        #get the provinces that are available
        select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id('ddlProvince'))
        option_indexes = range(1, len(select.options))

        #iterate through the provinces
        for index in option_indexes[:3]:
            select.select_by_index(index)
            #click the search button
            self.driver.find_element_by_id('cmdSearch').click()

            pageno = 2

            while True:
                #create a beautiful soup of the page source code
                s = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source)
                #get all links that match seeing practitioner profile
                r1 = re.compile(r'^PractitionerView\.aspx\?FILENO=([A-Z0-9-]+)$')
                #create a dictionary of the attributes
                x = {'href': r1}

                #so in the page source, find all links that have the attributes stated in x
                for a in s.findAll('a', attrs=x):
                    print 'View Doctor URL: ', urlparse.urljoin(self.driver.current_url, a['href'])
                    print 

                # Pagination
                try:                    
                    next_page_elem = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='%d']" % pageno)
                    print "Next page: ", next_page_elem
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    break # no more pages

                print 'page ', pageno, '\n'
                next_page_elem.click()

                pageno += 1

        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = DoctorScraper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

I am getting this error:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: {"errorMessage":"Element does not exist in cache","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"121","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:63135","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"tag name\", \"sessionId\": \"ef6d0590-a2d6-11e7-91fa-5773b3326267\", \"id\": \":wdc:1506442969197\", \"value\": \"option\"}","url":"/elements","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"elements","directory":"/","path":"/elements","relative":"/elements","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/elements","queryKey":{},"chunks":["elements"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/ef6d0590-a2d6-11e7-91fa-5773b3326267/element/:wdc:1506442969197/elements"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with this site is that the clickable elements frequently goes beyond the sight and it throws `element not clickable` error. However, I've already fixed it. If you have ChromeDriver installed in your machine, just run it and see the magic. It will flawlessly traverse all the pages no matter how many they are. I've checked it.

```
from selenium import webdriver ; import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

main_link = 'http://isystems.hpcsa.co.za/iregister/RegisterSearch.aspx'

def get_content(driver,wait,link):
    driver.get(link)
    driver.find_element_by_id('SearchChkb_5').click()
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlProvince'))
    select.select_by_visible_text('WESTERN CAPE')
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cmdSearch')))
    elem.click()
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    page_counter = 2
    while True:
        try:
            if not page_counter % 10 == 1:
                driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_counter)).click()
                page_counter += 1
            else:
               driver.find_elements_by_link_text("...")[-1].click() 
               time.sleep(2)
               driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
               page_counter += 1
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    try:
        get_content(driver,wait,main_link)
    finally:    
        driver.close()
```

And using Class:

```
from selenium import webdriver ; import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class DoctorScraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "http://isystems.hpcsa.co.za/iregister/RegisterSearch.aspx"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def controlling_pagination(self):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        page_counter = 2
        while True:
            try:
                if not page_counter % 10 == 1:
                    self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_counter)).click()
                    page_counter += 1
                else:
                   self.driver.find_elements_by_link_text("...")[-1].click() 
                   time.sleep(2)
                   self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                   page_counter += 1
            except NoSuchElementException:
                break

    def get_content(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('SearchChkb_5').click()
        select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id('ddlProvince'))
        select.select_by_visible_text('WESTERN CAPE')
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        elem = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cmdSearch')))
        elem.click()
        self.controlling_pagination()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = DoctorScraper()
    scraper.get_content()
```

Btw, take a look at the bottom of the image where you can see the changes of pages:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you Shahil. It worked perfectly past page 10 but it got stuck at page 20 and gave the similar error as in my question. Any idea why?

Comment: In my case it went through 100 of pages without throwing any error. However, check again. There might have been any technical difficulties. Thanks.

Comment: You are right. It’s some error but I have no idea where it is coming from. It’s stopping at different pages every time. Now it stopped at page 12.

Comment: You should probably tweak your `explicit wait` parameter. I did it with chrome.

Comment: I think something is happening after FILENO=7214156. All my computers are failing after that. And it’s coming up after page 11.

Comment: Okay. I'll give it a try tonight.

Comment: Thank you Shahin. I spent last night trying to figure it out (so I didn't just copy paste your advice :) )

Comment: See the edited code above. If it does what it is supposed to, don't forget to mark this as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if you face any issue executing the code. Thanks.

Comment: Since you posted your reply, I have been trying to figure out this error: WebdriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Comment: In case of making the Chromedriver run, I'm really helpless. Cause i feel feverish when it comes to install anything in my machine. However, you can count on the above code. Thanks.

Comment: Alright thanks Shahin. I will try this on my home computer. These work ones have too many restrictions. I will mark your answer as correct :)